# Solving sides of connected triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

[image: drawing of concept]

I have a problem where I need to find the distance to 4 points. I know the angle of each ray relative to every other ray, and I also know the distance between all points. I need to solve to find the distance from the origin to the points.

I tried using the law of sines to create ratios for the sides but couldn't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't see your image. Can you please check your link?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965002/calculate-position-based-on-angles-between-three-known-points/1965309#1965309).