# Find a the Position and Rotation of an Object in 3D Space Given the Pan and Tilt Angle to 3 Other Known Points.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, programming

**Goal**

I want to find the rotation and position of an object in the real world given the pan/tilt or azimuth/elevation angles between the object and 3 or more other points in the room. The rotation of the object should be relative to a fixed room axis. I then want to translate this formula into python code (please feel free to skip this part in the answer, I am mainly trying to figure out the process). If you do want to include code, please do not worry about memory or time performance.

**Known Information**

The points A, B, and C in 3D coordinates.
The pan/tilt angles between the light/observer relative to an local up and forward vector.

**Background Info**

Using a DMX light (a light with motors built into it), I can find the exact local pan and tilt rotation to point the light at any object in a room by manually adjusting values until the angle is correct. Because these lights use stepper motors the exact angle can be determined to point the light in the correct direction. The origin point in the room is chosen arbitrarily, and the position of the points is measured in the real world using a laser measure and can be accurate to about 10mm.

**Similar problems**

While researching this problem I came across a similar question which uses 2D space. My intuition was to break the problem down into 2 2D planes, but I unfortunately am not as good at math as I'd like to believe, and I have a bit of trouble reading mathematical syntax so I was not very successful.

[Calculate position based on angles between three known points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965002/calculate-position-based-on-angles-between-three-known-points)

**What I Have Tried**

*To clarity, I am not very good at 3D math so I tried to solve the problem by breaking it into 2 different 2D problems I could use that find the pan and tilt angles separately*

I'll spare you all my messy python code but what I did was the following:

Input:

- 2D room positions [-1, 0], [0, 1], and [1, 0]
- pan angles -90, 0, and +90

Expected Output:

- Observer point should be [0, 0]
- Observer rotation should be 0.

Process:

1. Calculate the point of intersection between the bisector of any two positions, and the circle formed by the bisector and those two positions:
   Half distance between 2 positions * inverse of slope between 2 positions * cotan(angle/2)
2. Calculate the 2 points intersection between all sets of 2 points and their bisector intersection.
3. Find the common point of intersection between the two sets of intersection points.

**Comments**

I think my approach for a point in 2D space is pretty solid, although I do receive NaN points and Inf values from time to time (probably a result of my poor understanding of the math). But I am not really sure how I can scale this up to 3D and how I can adjust the formula to account for the rotation of the object itself. Please feel free to build on my approach or discard it all together. Although I am proud of the attempt I made, I am pretty sure this is not the best way to approach this problem.

**Diagram**

[image: Problem Diagram]
*I am very sorry about the paint image, I know it is the Comic Sans of diagrams but please bear with me.*

**Concerns**

Given the use of this formula (creating an accurate digital twin of a lighting fixture), rotation accuracy is very important. Although a minor positional error doesn't make much of a difference over a long distance, and rotational error can vastly offset the final result. The area this is going to be used in is about 100 square meters so the rotation can have some error, but the more accurate the better.

**Real Example Data**

```
P1 = [16.54939424,-1.03074206,4.46979548]
pan1 = 168.657816434∘
tilt1 = −67.9983215076∘

P2 = [16.54939424,-4.79847669,6.71792244]
pan2 = 191.614099336∘
tilt2 = −80.7493705653∘

P3 = [-5.31398218,-0.97888645,5.2394251]
pan3 = 4.43350881209∘
tilt3 = −77.3176165408∘
```

**Example of Setup**

*This is not the real venue but instead somewhat similar outdoor venue, please note the upside down lights hanging from the trusses. What I want to find is their location relative to a fixed origin point (lets say the center of the stage on the ground) and the rotation they were installed at. For NDA reasons I cannot show the actual site of the installation, sorry*
[image]

Comment: Working in a 3D situation, but giving only 2D coordinates for points is confusing. Points in space require three coordinates to identify. Do you only know two of the three coordinates for your "known" points?

Comment: Also, the tilt angle is between the centerline of the light and a "vertical" reference direction. Is that vertical direction parallel to one of the coordinate axes of the room (most commonly the $z$ axis). And the pan angle is the angle between the plane formed by the centerline of the light and the vertical direction, and a reference plane. Is that second reference plane perpendicular to one of the other coordinate axes? If so, in both cases, which coordinate axes are they aligned with?

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for commenting. I started using 2D coordinates because I am not very familiar with this type of problem so I decided to start with something simpler. I know many people here are much more skilled at math than I am so I wanted to present the actual problem to you guys before I described my approach to a simpler version. I am sorry for the confusion. For testing you could assume any Z coordinate to test with. All dimensions of the 3D points will be known when the formula is used.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I also apologize for the confusion with the centerlines. In DMX lighting angles are measured relative to the rotation of the lights base and the lights up direction. In the room the pan center vector should typically be [0,0,1] and the tilt should be [0,-1,0] if all lights are installed correctly. Unfortunately these lights are installed by humans and can be slightly offset. This offset is what I am hoping to find with the algorithm by finding the real physical rotation and location in the room.

Comment: Please be aware however, some lighting companies will install lights at different 90 degree rotations to create different effects. They might also be on the ground or hanging upside down from the ceiling as well. In my case they are upside down and should be facing forward. Unfortunately the forward and up vectors cannot be guaranteed as know because of this. The only known information are the points X, Y, Z and the lights pan/tilt rotations towards them relative to an unknown forward/up. Sorry about the confusing problem, I added the known information to the question.

Comment: Sorry to add another layer of complexity, I also forgot to mention, the pan/tilt angles I have are relative to the objects forward/up directions which are not known.

Comment: I extremely doubt that the tilt axis-of-rotation vector has a constant orientation with respect to the room. Pan should rotate about a vertical axis as you've indicated, but the direction of the tilt axis varies with the pan angle. However, I hadn't asked about either direction. What I was asking about was how the directions of Pan $0^\circ$ and Tilt $0^\circ$ aligned with the room. Which you answered with the final comment. I now understand you. What you really want to know is how the Light coordinates align with the Room coordinates. I'll answer that later when I have time.

Comment: When you say "I want to find the rotation and position of an object in the real world given the pan/tilt or azimuth/elevation angles between the object and 3 or more other points in the room. The rotation of the object should be relative to a fixed room axis." does it mean that the object to be located is not a point?

Comment: @Cesareo Technically the object is not a point, however the object I am working with has something called a nodal offset. I'm not sure if you are familiar with the term or if it is specific to lighting and cameras but basically it is the point an object rotates around (basically it's center). If I know where that point is in a room, I can simply subtract the height * the up vector of this nodal offset to get the actual value I want later. I think for this problem you can assume it is a point but thank you for clarifying,  I know my explanation is a bit all over the place.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your help so far and helping me clarify the problem. Sorry I did not make the resting 0∘ rotations clear, I didn't think that was important to the problem so I excluded that bit of information. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Could you furnish us the object location associated to the data you gave us? This is necessary to certify the accuracy of the data given and know what margin of error we are dealing with.

Comment: @Cesareo Sorry Cesareo, unfortunately I don't actually know that position. I just wanted to include some real world data incase it was useful, but there is no way for me to get an accurate position of the light. It is suspended roughly 20 meters in the air so I can only get a rough estimate. I'm hoping this kind of algorithm can help me get around that issue. That is also why I tried using very simple numbers when I tried to solve the problem in 2D. I can try to make up an example case if helps, but it would not use real world measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as an extended comment.

The object position, as emanating from each point, is

$$
q_i = P_i - r_i(\cos t_i\cos p_i, \cos t_i\sin p_i, \sin t_i)\ \ \ i=1,\cdots, n
$$

Here

$$
\cases{
P_i = \text{Point coordinates}\\
r_i = \text{Distance from origin to given point}\\
t_i = \text{Tilt angle (in radians)}\\
p_i = \text{Pan angle (in radians)}
}
$$

One method to calculate $r_i$ is by minimizing the sum of squared residuals.

$$
\{r_i\} = \arg\min_{r_1}\sum_j\sum_{i\ne j} \|q_i-q_j\|^2
$$

so we have

$$
\mathscr{E}=\sum_i\sum_{j\ne i} \|P_i-P_j+r_i\hat u_i-r_j\hat u_j\|^2 
$$

and the conditions for minimum are

$$
\frac{\partial\mathscr{E} }{\partial r_i} = (P_i-P_j+r_i\hat u_i-r_j\hat u_j)\cdot\hat u_i = 0
$$

or

$$
(P_i-P_j)\cdot\hat u_i+r_i - r_j \hat u_i\cdot\hat u_j = 0
$$

Now, after solving the linear system in the unknowns $r_i$ we have as the unknown coordinates

$$
P^* = \frac 1n\sum_i (P_i -r_i^*\hat u_i)
$$

EDIT

This problem is equivalent to

$$
\{r_i,o\}=\arg\min_{r_i,o}\sum_{i=1}^n\|q_i-o\|^2,\ \ \ o = (o_x,o_y,o_z)
$$

with

$$
\cases{
o^* = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n q_i^*\\
\sum_{j=1}^n(P_j-r_j^*\hat u_j-o^*)\cdot\hat u_i = 0
}
$$

where $o$ is the object position.

The linear system to solve in this formulation is

$$
\left[\matrix{ &    & &\hat u_1^T\\ 
         & I_n& &\vdots\\
         &    & &\hat u_n^T\\
         \hat u_1&\cdots&\hat u_n& n I_3
}\right]\left[\matrix{r_1\\ \vdots \\ r_n\\ o}\right]=\left[\matrix{P_1\cdot\hat u_1\\ \vdots\\ P_n\cdot \hat u_n\\ \sum_i P_i}\right]
$$

Follows a python script implementing this procedure

```
import math
from scipy import linalg as la

n = 5;
conv = math.pi/180
pan = [103.21,178.58,-92.02,-0.035,68.36]
tilt = [43.06,-54.50,15.45,-56.15,-68.25]
points = [[1.33, 8.70, 9.52],
          [-5.23, 2.75,-7.98], 
          [2.91, -6.81, 6.28], 
          [8.10, 2.81, -3.87], 
          [5.12, 7.53, -9.62]]

def q(pan, tilt):
    ct = math.cos(conv*tilt)
    st = math.sin(conv*tilt)
    cp = math.cos(conv*pan)
    sp = math.sin(conv*pan)
    return [ct*cp, ct*sp, st]

hatu = []
for k in range(n):
    hatu.append(q(pan[k],tilt[k]))

def dot(u, v):
    n = len(u)
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += u[i]*v[i]
    return s


A = [[0 for x in range(n+3)] for y in range(n+3)] 

for i in range(n):
    A[i][i] = 1
for i in range(3):
    A[i+n][i+n] = n

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i][n+j] = hatu[i][j]
        A[n+j][i] = A[i][n+j]
    
B = [dot(points[i],hatu[i]) for i in range(n)]

for i in range(3):
    s = 0
    for j in range(n):
        s += points[j][i]
    B.append(s)

    
solro = la.solve(A, B)
print(solro[n:n+3])
```

Follows a MATHEMATICA script with randomly generated data to show the procedure

```
n = 5;
pan = {103.21,178.58,-92.02,-0.035,68.36}/180*Pi;
tilt = {43.06,-54.50,15.45,-56.15,-68.25}/180*Pi;
points = {{1.32704, 8.70404, 9.52376}, {-5.23097, 2.75125,-7.97803}, {2.91049, -6.80956, 6.27576}, {8.09571, 2.81425, -3.86921}, {5.12395, 7.53377, -9.61743}}
q[r_, pan_, tilt_] := r {Cos[tilt] Cos[pan], Cos[tilt] Sin[pan], Sin[tilt]}

del = Table[points[[k]] - q[r[k], pan[[k]], tilt[[k]]], {k, 1, n}];
obj = Sum[Sum[(del[[i]] - del[[j]]) . (del[[i]] - del[[j]]), {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 2, n}];
vars = Table[r[k], {k, 1, n}]
sol = Minimize[obj, vars]
targets = del /. sol[[2]];
target = Total[targets] / n;

gr0 = Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]}]

gr1 = {ParametricPlot3D[del[[1]], {r[1], 0, (r[1] /. sol[[2]])}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}],
ParametricPlot3D[del[[2]], {r[2], 0, (r[2] /. sol[[2]])}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}],
ParametricPlot3D[del[[3]], {r[3], 0, (r[3] /. sol[[2]])}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}],
ParametricPlot3D[del[[4]], {r[4], 0, (r[4] /. sol[[2]])}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}],
ParametricPlot3D[del[[5]], {r[5], 0, (r[5] /. sol[[2]])}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}]};
gr2 = Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[target]}];
Show[gr0, gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

NOTE

The angular data was generated including a random error in the range $\pm 3^{\circ}$. The points are in red, and the object position is in black.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to work pretty well if there are enough data points (I tried using 3 points at different 90∘ angles and it was pretty far off but adding a 4th point gave a better answer). However is there a way to determine the rotation of the object itself given the position returned by this formula and the pan/tilt angles provided? I mentioned this earlier but a pan angle of 0∘ should point the light towards the local forward vector and a tilt angle of 0∘ should point the light towards the local up vector. I don't know if this helps but pan applied before tilt.

Comment: Also thank you very much for the python code. That saved me a lot of time testing things but feel free not to include it if it too much trouble. Luckily I am much better at programming than math.

Comment: I hate to press you for more after you already helped with the position part of the problem, but have you had any luck figuring out the rotation? I've tried a few things on my own but honestly this is way out of my understanding. If possible I could really use an answer before April 1st because I would like to use these functions to calibrate some stage lighting for a concert. Sorry if I sound ungrateful for your help so far, I'm just kind of stuck and under a lot of pressure with this problem.

Comment: If it is the orientation that I am understanding, to know it, we need to know the relative positions of three axes integral to the object, or then, four non-coplanar points on the object. To clarify this, it would be interesting to have a diagram that shows the type of orientation you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Unfortunately I do not know the real forward, up, right vectors of the object. They should be [1,0,0], [0,-1,0] and [0,0,-1] if the light is properly installed in the ceiling, but most likely they will be installed with small offsets due to human error (for example they might accidentally rotate the light 5 degrees left by mistake or intentionally decide to rotate it by 90 degrees so it fits better on the equipment). Unfortunately no point on the object is known other than the one calculated by your initial algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but I added a picture of a similar venue to the questions description. Sorry if my replies come in late, I'll try to check in every hour or so to see if you have questions/comments so I don't waste too much of your time. As for the bounty on the question, I know it will expire soon but I will re-add it if I can before I accept the answer. I don't know if it is important to you but as a avid video game player would hurt my soul if you did not get properly awarded the extra internet points for the time you invested in my question.

Comment: In other words, what we want is: given a point on the stage that must be illuminated by a spotlight located in a certain location, what must be its inclination and pan for this to happen.

Comment: I see. The pan and tilt of the light are already known, as well as the position the light shines on. We plan to record 5 sets of relative pan/tilt rotations for 5 different positions for each light a day or two in advance. I don't think we can figure out what the rotation/surface normal of he illuminated point is since it is just a spot on the wall we mark with tape. Sorry if I am still misunderstanding your meaning (if you could upload a diagram of what you mean I might be able to understand better).

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the setup, we have an object with a reference frame attached to it, that specifies the object's orientation in space with respect to a world coordinate system (the coordinate system chosen for the room).  In this world coordinate system we have the coordinates of $3$ points $A,B, C$.  The relationship between local object coordinates and the world coordinates are as follows

$ p = p_0 + R_0 p' $

where $p$ is the world coordinate vector, and $p'$ is the local coordinate vector.  $p_0$ is the position vector of the origin of the local coordinate frame relative to the world.  And $R_0$ is a rotation matrix.

We are given the pan/tilt angles of the the three known points relative to the local frame.  So we can write

$ p_k = p_0 + R_0 p'_k , k = 1 , 2, 3 $

where $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are the world coordinates of points $A,B,C$.
and

$p'_k = s_k \ u_k $

where $u_k$ is the following unit vector

$ u_k = ( \sin \theta_k \cos \phi_k , \sin \theta_k  \sin \phi_k , \cos \theta_k ) , k = 1, 2, 3$

The angles $\theta_k$, $\phi_k$ are the tilt/pan angles and are given.
As points $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are known, the distances between them are known.  As the vectors $u_k$ are known, the angles between them are known.  This information is sufficient to determine the distances $s_k, \ k = 1, 2, 3$, as follows.

Let $\phi_1 $ be the angle between the two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ , $\phi_2$ be the angle between the two vectors $u_2$ and $u_3$ , and $\phi_3$ the angle between $u_1$ and $u_3$, then from the law of cosines, we have:

$ \overline{p_1 p_2}^2 = s_1^2 + s_2^2 - 2 s_1 s_2 \cos \phi_1 $

$ \overline{p_2 p_3}^2 = s_2 ^2 + s_3^2 - 2 s_2 s_3 \cos \phi_2 $

$ \overline{p_3 p_1}^2 = s_1^2 + s_3^2 - 2 s_1 s_3 \cos \phi_3 $

Solving this system numerically, we obtain $s_1, s_2, s_3$.

Now we have the following system

$ p_1 = p_0 + s_1 R_0 u_1 $

$ p_2 = p_0 + s_2 R_0 u_2 $

$ p_3 = p_0 + s_3 R_0 u_3 $

So that

$ p_1 - p_2 = R_0 (s_1 u_1 - s_2 u_2) $

$ p_1 - p_3 = R_0 (s_1 u_1 - s_3 u_3) $

Further, using the cross product on both sides, we get

$ (p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) = R_0 \left( (s_1 u_1 - s_2 u_2) \times (s_1 u_1 - s_3 u_3 ) \right) $

Now define the matrices $F$ and $G$ as follows:

$ F = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 - p_2 && p_1 - p_3 && (p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) \end{bmatrix} $

$G = \begin{bmatrix} (s_1 u_1 - s_2 u_2 ) && (s_1 u_1 - s_3 u_3) && (s_1 u_1 - s_2 u_2) \times (s_1 u_1 - s_3 u_3 ) \end{bmatrix} $

Then,

$ F = R_0 G $

Therefore,

$ R_0 = F G^{-1} $

Now that we have obtained the rotation matrix $R_0$ which specifies the orientation of the object with respect to the world, we finally solve for the position of the object using one of the position equations above, for example,

$p_1 = p_0 + s_1 R_0 u_1 $

The only unknown vector here is $p_0$, all the other quantities are known, hence,

$ p_0 = p_1 - s_1 R_0 u_1 $

Now the specification of the object's position and orientation is complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try testing this out tomorrow morning but it might take me some time since I am not very familiar with this math and I need to translate it into python. I also noticed a small typo with the cross produce of (p1-p2)x(p1-p3), at least I think I did. If you know how to translate this into code that would be greatly appreciated but I can take a crack at it myself tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminDangerJohnson for noting the typo.  Corrected.

Comment: Thank for adding the VBA code but it looks like it calls a bunch of functions that are not built into VBA such as rd_xyz_1. Are these from some plugin or were they not included.

Comment: If you can provide those functions as well I would really appreciate it. I'm actually pretty stumped with this VBA script myself. It took a while to figure out that Dim points(3,3) As Double was actually creating a 4x4 matrix of doubles. I tried a couple of online converters but they seem to be very inconsistent. But I'll keep trying, if it works on your end the code must be valid, so now I just need to figure out how to translate it.